# I am noticing extra and unnecessary data in my table after fixing the type error cannot convert the series to class float

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, typeerror, data-analysis

For example, the first thing I noticed when obtaining the total number of students was that when I ran the cell of my code,

```
# Get the total number of students.
student_count = school_data_complete_df.count()
student_count
```

I get the following results as expected:
[image]

Even the sampled output provides the same results, so I am correct. However, when I run the data frames onto a table, I get the following results for the Total Students column:

[image]

this is what the correct sampled output is supposed to be:

[image]

I am noticing similar anomalies in later sections when running my passing percentages for math and reading students. To start off, I am determining the passing grades for math and reading assessment tests:

```
passing_math = school_data_complete_df["math_score"] >= 70
passing_reading = school_data_complete_df["reading_score"] >= 70
```

The output I am getting is slightly different from the expected output:

[image]

I noticed this just now

Here is the correct output:

[image]

The rest of my code runs normally

```
# Get all the students that are passing reading in a new DataFrame.
passing_reading = school_data_complete_df[school_data_complete_df["reading_score"] >= 70]

# Calculate the number of students passing math.
passing_math_count = passing_math["student_name"].count()

# Calculate the number of students passing reading.
passing_reading_count = passing_reading["student_name"].count()

print(passing_math_count)
print(passing_reading_count)
```

Until I reached this error:

```
# Calculate the percent that passed math.
passing_math_percentage = passing_math_count / float(student_count) * 100

# Calculate the percent that passed reading.
passing_reading_percentage = passing_reading_count / float(student_count) * 100
```

The information after this cell of code says the following:

[image]

However, when I tried to run the code, I was receiving a type error cannot convert the series to class float. I mitigated this issue by editing my cell of code to look like this:

```
# Calculate the percent that passed math.
passing_math_percentage = passing_math_count / student_count.astype("float") * 100

# Calculate the percent that passed reading.
passing_reading_percentage = passing_reading_count / student_count.astype("float") * 100
```

Now I am not getting an error but this is what my overall table looks like now after creating a district summary dataframe:

```
# Adding a list of values with keys to create a new DataFrame.
district_summary_df = pd.DataFrame(
          [{"Total Schools": school_count,
          "Total Students": student_count,
          "Total Budget": total_budget,
          "Average Math Score": average_math_score,
          "Average Reading Score": average_reading_score,
          "% Passing Math": passing_math_percentage,
         "% Passing Reading": passing_reading_percentage,
        "% Overall Passing": overall_passing_percentage}])
district_summary_df
```

[image]

I only want the percentage values to appear on my table and one number to appear in the column of total students. So the correct sampled output looks like this:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. We do not know the types of all your variables.

Comment: What do you want specifically?

Comment: A sample of your dataframe `df.head().to_dict()` and also the definitions of all variables you used in your post: `passing_math_count`, `student_count` etc.

Comment: Should I post the specific info on a new question or can I post it here? There was some critical info that I missed anyways. I should have mentioned the total students column.

Comment: You can just edit the post to include all relevant information.

Comment: Yeah I had just taken care of that.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Can you post tables in the same way I posted code without the screenshots of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `student_count` should be a float so count a single column
2. For the passing count, use `sum` to count all the rows that are `True`. You are currently using `count` which will count all rows (both `True` and `False`).

```
#count the number of students using a single column so the result is a float
student_count = school_data_complete_df["Student ID"].count()

#get passing math and reading masks
passing_math = school_data_complete_df["math_score"] >= 70
passing_reading = school_data_complete_df["reading_score"] >= 70

# Calculate the number of students
passing_math_count = passing_math.sum()
passing_reading_count = passing_reading.sum()

passing_math_percentage = passing_math_count/student_count * 100
passing_reading_percentage = passing_reading_count/student_count * 100
```

Comment: So do you want me to edit my code by including the variables above passing_math_percentage and passing_reading_percentage all in one cell?

Comment: I'm assuming wherever I see the variables I declared I update them even though each of those variables are located in different cells.

Comment: It doesn't matter which cells your put your variable declarations in. The formulas are what you should be changing. Not sure I understand your confusion.

Comment: I still received a type error with your edits. I'll screenshot them to you just to clarify if I am supposed to make the edits with the cells where they belong.

Comment: It doesn't seem like I can attach screenshots under the comments, so I'll just update my question.

Comment: I updated your version of the code with the the updated formulas in one cell. This time, I am getting a key error for student name

Comment: When I run the edited version I get a NameError: name 'passing_mathsum' is not defined. Even when I define the passing_mathsum variable, I received a type error.

Comment: Typo. `passing_math.sum()`

Answer (score 0):

From the second image, [image]

Total Students column does not look right

Comment: Actually I forgot to bring up that error as well.